# What is the right approach to deal with Rails db/schema.rb file in GIT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Should we include `schema.rb` while commiting to GIT? or should we ignore it? what is the right approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the preferred way to manage schema.rb in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737854/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-manage-schema-rb-in-git)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Well the standard `schema.rb` file for Rails 2 has this at the end of the comment block at the top of the file:

```
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.
```

The Rails 3 `schema.rb` that I have kicking around says the same thing. I think the comment says it all.

---

**Update in response to comments:**
Yes, mistakes can be made and you can get conflicting changes and bugs mangling your `schema.rb` but that's why you want it under revision control, revision control allows you to keep track of everything and backup when needed. There is only one thing in your entire source tree that specifies your database schema and that is `schema.rb`. Your database schema absolutely is a critical artifact and anything that important needs to be tracked in revision control.

Any update/merge problems with `schema.rb` should be sorted out just by sorting out your conflicting migrations so `schema.rb` will get fixed as a side effect of fixing the real problem.

Yes, `schema.rb` is a generated file but it is only generated in the sense that your text editor generates your `pancake.rb` model file or an unedited scaffold file is generated.

Yes, you could rebuild your `schema.rb` file by building a new database and then running all of your migrations. But, you should clear out your old migrations now and then to avoid having to check hundreds of migration files every time you `rake db:migrate` so "rebuild and run all the migrations" often isn't an option in a highly active project.

Comment: do you commit the changes in this file to git, for example, after running a new migration?

Comment: @mu..@pcg79...I used to commit schema.rb initially into the GIT and then do not commit to the GIT,the changes made afterward.If anyone commit by mistake,will result in error while pulling.Then will have to checkout the file and pull.I am afraid this error will come when I commit the changes to the GIT.The problem is the schema.rb is overwrited each time a migration is executed.eg.the schema.rb from git have the schema updated but when we pull it,we will have to run `rake db:migrate` to make local db uptodate.This will update the `schema.rb` file and may result in error while pulling from git

Comment: @rubyprince, @pcg79: I added an update to address (at least that's the idea) some of the issues in the comments.

Comment: It seems like this would be appropriate to check into version control but not necessarily push around to your team members. "How?" you might ask.
Branches my dear Watson, Branches.

Comment: Well, after starting commiting schema file to the GIT for multiple projects, right from the start of the project, I would say we have had only small minor conflicts, usually around the last migration number, which can be easily resolved. So, it had been a smooth ride overall.

Comment: @rubyprince: That's my experience as well, I've never had a conflict problem with `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` that wasn't solved by sorting out the migrations.

Comment: how about the migration files themselves?  do you commit those as well?

Comment: @sircapsalot: Yes, of course the migrations get committed. How else would changes get to other team members or the production systems? However, migrations get periodically deleted when they're no longer relevant and they start cluttering up the migrations directory.

Comment: sorry - it wasn't an "of course" for me.  but yes, ok that makes sense. thanks

Comment: @fatfrog Yes but "There is only one thing in your entire source tree that specifies your database schema and that is `schema.rb`". Sure you can try starting with an empty database and then running all the migrations but historic migrations can fail in all sorts of ways, the [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for-questionmark) even says so. `schema.rb` (or `structure.sql`) is the only accurate representation of your database schema, not tracking it is a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The schema file is used to configure your database when using rake db:reset and other commands.  Migrations should only be used when changing the database schema and will always result in a new schema file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not included on .gitignore by default. So, I think that you would not have a problem including it(I do in my projects, without any problem).

Comment: I include it in initial commit but, do you commit the changes to your schema file to git, for example, after running a new migration?

Comment: just as a part of commiting my other changes. I would not pay any more attention on commiting migrations more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't commit this file to Git, because it create when I launch `rake db:migrate`.

If I will commit this file to Git, I cannot pull new changes from server after each `db:migrate`.

Comment: I think if your `schema.rb` doesn't match what is generated by your migrations then you have another problem that you are ignoring by not committing `schema.rb`

Comment: I am agree with include `schema.r` to git but what I have to do when run in `development` enviroment `rake db:migrate` and then also in `production` enviroment???

Comment: @inye: You `rake db:migrate` in production, that will compare the `schema_migrations` table to your `db/migrate` directory to see what needs to be run to bring your production database up to date.