# Proper method for committing schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git

The general consensus is that when migrating you should check schema.rb into version control.

[What is the right approach to deal with Rails db/schema.rb file in GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450263/what-is-the-right-approach-to-deal-with-rails-db-schema-rb-file-in-git)

My question is this- if my senior dev creates a migration & checks schema.rb, I pull the repo down and migrate on my end and it shows schema.rb has been changed- do I also commit my version of schema.rb and check that into version control as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450263/what-is-the-right-approach-to-deal-with-rails-db-schema-rb-file-in-git

Comment: We usually leave that commit to be made by whoever is deploying the migration - At the time of deployment, the migration has to be anyway run, and that is the most correct version for `schema.rb`. A check-in before can lead to possible conflicts between devs, and thus incorrect information in the repo.

Comment: I prefer to add the file to .gitignore

Answer (score 4):

In theory, your `schema.rb` should be identical to the one that Senior Dev has committed, after you do the migration.  If it isn't, then one of two things have happened:

- Senior Dev actually forgot to commit `schema.rb`
- The migration made a change that is not recorded by `schema.rb` in a consistent way (there are many creative uses of migrations that might lead to this, let alone bugs).

You should double check that Senior Dev has, in fact, committed `schema.rb` after they ran the migration.  If they have, you should throw away the changes on your version of `schema.rb` in favour of theirs.  If they have NOT, then you should commit your version of `schema.rb`, effectively correcting their mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should check-in your version of `schema.rb`. This would make sure that the entire team is working on the same version. Merging should be done whenever there are new changes to the schema. Your contributions to a project which alter the database are still contributions to the product, and as such are required to be checked-in.

The specific process of merging may differ per team. Some teams have a QA team which handles these things, others have a deployment team which handles this stuff. However, the case, *communication* is key. Try to keep your senior developer in the loop with your schema changes.